# Installing ejbca_ce_6_1_1 on CentOS 6.6 with jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

Tags: java, linux, ant, jboss, ejbca

i am trying to install ejbca from this guide:http://ejbcacentos.blogspot.gr/2014/04/how-to-install-ejbca-611-on-centos-65.html

when i type the command sudo -u jboss ant deploy (it is on the chapter Installing EJBCA/initial deployment of the guide) i take back this java error:

/opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/build.xml:79: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory

i have set the java home in /etc/profile

i don't know what may caused this error and i can 't find something relevant to this on google. if anyone knows what may caused this error i really appreciate any help you can provide.

here is the full terminal output:

```
[root@localhost ejbca]# sudo -u jboss ant deploy
Buildfile: build.xml

customejbca.message:
         [echo] No custom changes to merge.

appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

deprecated:check:

customejbca.message:

appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    deprecated:notify:

    cleanDistDir:

    customejbca.message:
         [echo] No custom changes to merge.

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    dependecy-check-clean:

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    clean:

    -pre-init:

    -init-private:

    -pre-init-libraries:

    -init-private-libraries:

    -init-libraries:

    -init-user:

    -init-project:

    -init-macrodef-property:

    -do-init:

    -post-init:

    -init-check:

    -init-ap-cmdline-properties:

    -init-macrodef-javac-with-processors:

    -init-macrodef-javac-without-processors:

    -init-macrodef-javac:

    -init-macrodef-junit:

    -init-debug-args:

    -init-macrodef-nbjpda:

    -init-macrodef-debug:

    -init-macrodef-java:

    -init-presetdef-jar:

    -init-ap-cmdline-supported:

    -init-ap-cmdline:

    init:

    -deps-clean-init:

    deps-clean:
        [mkdir] Created dir: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/modules/batchenrollment-gui/build

    -warn-already-built-clean:
    [propertyfile] Updating property file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/modules/batchenrollment-gui/build/built-clean.properties

    -check-call-dep:

    -maybe-call-dep:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    clean:

    -do-clean:
       [delete] Deleting directory /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/modules/batchenrollment-gui/build

    -post-clean:

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    cesecore-common.clean:

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    cesecore-common.clean:

    cesecore-entity.clean:

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    cesecore-common.clean:

    cesecore-entity.clean:

    cesecore-ejb-interface.clean:

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    clean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    validationtoolclean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    statedumpclean:

    customejbca.message:

    appserver.error.message:
         [echo] jndi.properties.file: /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/conf/jndi.properties.jboss7

    ctclean:

    failinproduction-deprecation:

    fail-unless-appserver-detected:
         [echo] appserver.home: /opt/jboss
         [echo] appserver.type: jboss
         [echo] appserver.subtype: jboss7

    testforgnujava:

    BUILD FAILED
    /opt/ejbca_ce_6_1_1/build.xml:79: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, your question is not very readable. Please edit it and use code block formatting for your source code. Also, be sure to choose a good title and include some text explaining what your problem is and how you tried to solve it already. This will make useful answers much more likely and decrease didactic comments like this one ;-) See also [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: thank you Michael, i hope that it is more readable now.

Comment: Thank you, it is much better now. For your next question, you could also use backticks for inline code parts (`example`) and be sure to use capital letters where appropriate. This way, we can provide quality information for other people with similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting APPSRV_HOME=$JBOSS_HOME in your profile.